# Interactive Pop Gesture Recognizer blocking button touchupinside event in custom uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UITableViewController that is pushed from a RootViewController. In the UITableView for the UITableViewController, I'm using a custom cell which has a button at the left with frame: CGRectMake(0,0,30,30).

It seems like when I set self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO; in the UITableViewController, the touch events for the button are received, but if I set it to enabled = YES, the touch events on the button are lost:

Here's my code for creating the button inside the custom tableviewcell.

```
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,30,30);
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self addSubview:button];
```

Any thoughts/suggestions on how I can fix this would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `cancelsTouchesInView` property on the gesture recognizer to `NO`.  The default is `YES`, which means the view to which it's attached won't get to also handle the touches.